# How to update/reload data from JSON in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, tableview, reload

I have 2 View controllers. First one parses data from a JSON file. Data retrieved is, then, passed to TableView in second controller. The problem is, when Data is edited on the JSON file, the Tableview still shows the old data that was previously loaded. Which one needs to be refreshed, TableView or JSON, or both? I understand that I should implement dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() but I need more clarification. Many articles discuss this but I have yet to find one that would work! Any info would be appreciated!

Comment: The TableView represents your `[JSON Model object]` so when the Model got changed you need to call `tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: Thanks for responding. Where do I place it?

Comment: reloadInputViews() did the trick. In my Example: cell.reloadInputViews()